# I want to seperate json array elements based on their duplication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to seperate elements both duplicated and non duplicated into seperate array as shown below:

Input :

```
let test = [
 {
  "id1": "1"
 },
 {
  "id1": "2"
 },
 {
  "id1": "2"
 }
]
```

output:

```
ans1 = [
 {
  "id1": "1"
 }
]

ans2 = [
 {
  "id1": "2"
 },
 {
  "id1": "2"
 }
]
```

I have tried using for loop but i was not able to find answer and now I am trying to use other methods of array.

Comment: You mention trying a for loop but haven't provided the code you've tried. Provide it so we can see what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let test = [
    {
     "id1": "1"
    },
    {
     "id1": "2"
    },
    {
     "id1": "2"
    }
   ]

const isRepeated = (element, arr, repeats)=>{
    if (arr.length === 0) return false


    for (const x in arr){
        if ( JSON.stringify( arr[x] ) === JSON.stringify(element) )  
        repeats.push( arr.splice( x,1 ) )  // remove repeated element from uniques and add it to repeats
        return true 
    }

    return false 
}


let ans1 = []  // uniques
let ans2 = []  // repeats

for (const x of test){

    if ( isRepeated(x, ans1) ) {
        ans2.push(x)
    } else {
        ans1.push(x)
    }   
}

console.log('ans1 is: ', ans1)
console.log('ans2 is: ', ans2)
```